# Bandwidth comparision over different channels

Tags: bandwidth

I wanted to compare how much bandwidth is consumed when I make a group call(voice) over Whatsapp, Discord or Teams. I wanted to do the analysis and choose one platform which will consume less bandwidth. Is it possible to do such analysis using a tool or some method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, you can use "Resource monitor". It is already installed on every windows machine and it shows the bandwidth used by specific programs. On iOS it is not possible and for android, there are a lot of apps that do the job

Comment: I'm on windows but I'm specifically talking about the mobile apps here, and I want to have that analysis on my internet connection in phone(one provided by SIM)